# NPM install, totally unknown -E prefix

Tags: reactjs, npm, package

While installing MATERIAL TAILWIND package, I am noticing a notation that I have never seen, while installing a npm package
`npm i -E @material-tailwind/react`

What is this -E thing?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 9):

`-` denotes switches in posix programs, similar to how `/` works in the windows cmd.exe
They modify the command to do something different

In the case of npm install:

```
aliases: npm i, npm add
common options: [-P|--save-prod|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional|--save-peer] [-E|--save-exact] [-B|--save-bundle] [--no-save] [--dry-run]
```

-E, --save-exact: Saved dependencies will be configured with an exact version rather than using npm's default semver range operator.

From: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install -E - the flag is short for --save-exact, use this when you need an exact version as opposed to a semver range.
```

for more details, you can visit here.

https://alligator.io/nodejs/npm-commands-you-should-know/